# Uprgading Rails 3 ActiveResource App to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeresource

We have a rails 3 app that makes heavy use of active resource and we are looking to upgrade to rails 4. From what I've read it sounds like active resource was removed from rails 4 because of it's threading model. ActiveResource has some really nice features, so it would be nice to keep it, but if there's a reasonable chance it will cause problems this might be a good time to look at alternatives.  Would appreciate any insights from anyone who may have already gone down this path.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just add the gem and check if you encounter anything strange (can't provide insights but that would be the first I would try).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html

> ```
> Extraction of features to gems
>
> In Rails 4.0, several features have been extracted into gems. You can simply add the extracted gems to your Gemfile to bring the functionality back.
> ```